# What's the name of this project structure?

Tags: spring-boot

I was looking for some project structures for learning and found this one, I know that it's the recommended but couldn't find it's name.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you are looking at the package structure shown in the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code).

I would say it’s called *“package by feature”*, which is about keeping all code related to a given a feature in the the same package.
It contrasts with the *“package by layer”* approach, which groups all the code by layers and technical concerns.